# Setting a State in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my project, there's an instance where I have to implement a Switch mechanism where the application will Switch between 2 Options on SQL Query. Two options are based on Time and Count of Votes.

Can you set a state of sort to tackle the situation (Like in React) or how do you tackle this sort of a Situation.

Now by default the application queries the record by count of votes.

```
function getPosts($limit, $offset) {
        if ($offset > 0) {
            $offset = ($offset - 1) * $limit;
        }
        //$selectedQuery = 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT ' . $limit . ' OFFSET ' . $offset;
        $selectedQuery = 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY upvotes DESC LIMIT ' . $limit . ' OFFSET ' . $offset;
        $result['rows'] = $this->db->query($selectedQuery);
        $result['num_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results($this->posts);
        return $result;
}
```

I want to switch the *selectedQuery*. How do I tackle this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to run either of those queries so only one is performed per call to your getPosts function?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yeah, I have set 2 Buttons in the View to switch between. But I can't figure out how to Set a State kind of a thing to switch between the 2 SQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would achieve this with a config item. However I am not certain why a simple check of the vote count would not help you decide which SQL statement to apply.

For using config items you would set your default config item value in your own config file, the set it when you want it to 'switch' to another value.

Alternatively, you could just add your config value to the default config file. Your config file can be autoloaded in autoload.php as well if you need it to.

It is all well described in the docs here:http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html#config-class

But in summary:

Load config file

```
 $this->config->load('sql_select_switch');
```

Read config setting

```
 $this->config->item('selected_query');
```

Set config setting

```
 $this->config->set_item('selected_query', 'item_value');
```

You can set and read the setting from anywhere in your application. If you only have two settings, a default and an alternative setting, you can just set the value to TRUE or FALSE.

Does this achieve what you were looking for? Hope it helps.